# Sparse matrix dot product keeping only N-max values per result row

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I've got a very huge csr sparse matrix `M`. I want to get dot product of this matrix to itself (`M.dot(M.T)`) and keep only `N` max values per each row in the result matrix `R`. The problem is that dot product `M.dot(M.T)` raises `MemoryError`. So I created modified implementation of dot function, that looks like:

```
def dot_with_top(m1, m2, top=None):
    if top is not None and top > 0:
        res_rows = []
        for row_id in xrange(m1.shape[0]):

            row = m1[row_id]
            if row.nnz > 0:
                res_row = m1[row_id].dot(m2)
                if res_row.nnz > top:
                    args_ids = np.argsort(res_row.data)[-top:]
                    data = res_row.data[args_ids]
                    cols = res_row.indices[args_ids]
                    res_rows.append(csr_matrix((data, (np.zeros(top), cols)), shape=res_row.shape))
                else:
                    res_rows.append(res_row)
            else:
                res_rows.append(csr_matrix((1, m1.shape[0])))
        return sparse.vstack(res_rows, 'csr')
    return m1.dot(m2)
```

It works fine but it's a bit slow. Is it possible to make this calculation faster or maybe you know some already existing method that do it faster?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compute the covariance matrix for some high-dimensional sparse dataset. What are you planning on using it for? Depending on what your ultimate goal is, there may be ways to avoid having to compute the covariance matrix explicitly.

Comment: @ali_m I'm computing cosine similarity matrix for item-based collaborative filtering needs. According to the method I need only 30 max elements per item.

Comment: Can you change it to work with blocks of rows at a time, rather than just one?  10 steps using 1000 rows should be faster than 10,000 steps.

Comment: I'd suggest profiling.  For example which is taking more time, the `row.dot(m2)` line (do the `mi[]` only once per loop), or collecting the 30 values?  Also is it better to make a `csr` at each step, or to collect the `data,row,col` for all arrays?  A `vstack `or final `csr_matrix`? Look at the internals of `bmat` (which is what `vstack` uses).

Comment: @hpaulj I thought about blocks, but the slowest part of method is sorting. I must sort items in each row even I use blocks. That's why solution with blocks doesn't give big improvements

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your loop over the number of row in a function, and call this function with the multiprocessing.Pool() object.
This will parallelize the execution of your loop and should add a nice speedup.

Example :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(row_id): 
# define here your function inside the loop
    return vstack(res_rows, 'csr')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4) # if you have 4 cores in your processor
    p.map(f, xrange(m1.shape[0]))
```

source : https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Note that some python-implemented function already use multiprocessing (common in numpy), so you should check your processor activity when your script is running before implementing this solution.

Comment: each process will need the copy of huge `M` matrix (for dot product). It's memory expensive solution.

Comment: I have implemented this. I had two 20GB arrays and had to do cosine distance (so you can use it for dot). I will soon send a pull request to scipy. Give me few hours - I will paste bin it.